# KOMA-script: locally align chapter title

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I would like chapter titles added with `\chapter{title}` to be aligned to the right (i.e. with `\raggedleft`), but everything else that classifies as a chapter (i.e. a chapter added with `\addchap{title}` or the title of the Bibliography) to remain aligned to the left of the page.

The solution I found aligns every chapter heading to the left. Is it possible to change this locally within the document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter} 
\lipsum[1-3]

\addchap{A chapter that should be flushleft}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\originalchapterlineswithprefixformat}{}
\let\originalchapterlineswithprefixformat\chapterlineswithprefixformat

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\Ifstr{#2}{}{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}}
    {}%
  \originalchapterlineswithprefixformat{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The first chapter} 
\lipsum[1-3]

\addchap{A chapter that should be flushleft}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**KOMA-Script version 3.27** provides additional hooks. Then you can use

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/chapter}{\chapteralignment}
\newcommand*\chapteralignment[1]{%
  \IfUseNumber{\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft}{\let\raggedchapter\raggedright}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The first chapter} 
\lipsum[1-3]

\addchap{A chapter that should be flushleft}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```